# Will the enemies killed by the explosion caused from Arcane Destruction prolong my Archon duration

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-wizard

[The Arcane Destruction on the Archon skill](http://us.battle.net/d3/en/class/wizard/active/archon) causes an explosion when you transform to the Archon form, causing 450% weapon damage as Arcane to all enemies within 15 yards. Will the enemies killed by the explosion will count as enemies killed by the Archon form and increase the time of the form?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the timer for Archon can't go above 15 seconds, and so it doesn't matter if they count or not as when you enter Archon form you are already capped at 15 seconds.

Comment: I have reached 30 seconds with archon.

Comment: Yeah. I got to 2 minutes, then did a lot of back tracking to pick up loot

Comment: @Justin, I got way over 4 minutes from the first mini boss at ACT IV, the one with the many shadow thingies.

Comment: @Philipp Do you mean that Archon lasted 30 seconds as a result of killing more enimied, or that the "time remaining" buff icon listed the duration as > 15 seconds?

Comment: The first, as a result of killing enemies my timer went up.

Comment: @Justin for me the buff icon listed remaining time as 3 minutes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, Arcane Destruction kills do not count towards increasing the time spent in Archon form. I tested by taking my wizard to Iskatu's fight in Normal, building up a lot of shadows and then blasting them by activating Archon form. The resulting timer was still 15 seconds :(.

I actually expected the opposite, but it seems that Arcane Destruction isn't counted among the archon kills for increasing the timer.